# How to port console and keyboard control in C to R when compiling c code into R with GCC in Windows?

Tags: c, r, gcc, io

I use GCC to compile some existed C code into a DLL for R under Windows. I included R.h for Rprintf, etc. The DLL can work through .C() in R.

The question is, however, the IO functions getchar(), screen refresh flush(stdout) in C seem lost in the R console. When the result R script works on a long job, the R console seems freeze even I used Rprintf and fflush in C before GCC. In addition, scanf() and other IO could not pause the R console for key input. Any points will be appriciated.

Comment: Are you interacting with R through RGui?  If so is the output being buffered (check Misc -> Buffered Output)